# Editing input name and id after cloning table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After clicking the button, the last row of the table is cloned. Every row has different input labels with names and ids ending in "_" + number of row where they are.

The new row added to the table include the same fields but the names and ids are not increasing in each row.

After checking similar questions I thought of adding the following code in my jquery function (code is commented in snippet).

```
$('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').find("input").each(function (index, label){
    input.id = input.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    input.name = input.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
});
```

But it doesn't change the attributes and I get the following error in the browser's console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined"

What is wrong with the function?
Thanks for your help.

```js
$("#cargarFamilias").click(function() {

  var currentCount = $("#tablaFamilias tr").length;
  var newCount = currentCount + 1;
  $('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last');
  /*
  $('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').find("input").each(function(index, label) {
    input.id = input.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    input.name = input.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
  });
  */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a id="cargarFamilias" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa "></i> Cargar conceptos de familia
</a>

<table id="tablaFamilias" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <th>Partida</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Plazo de entrega</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>UM</th>
    <th>Lugar de entrega</th>
    <th>Dirección de entrega</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="partida_1" id="partida_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="codigo_1" id="codigo_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="descripcion_1" id="descripcion_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="plazoentrega_1" id="plazoentrega_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad_1" id="cantidad_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="um_1" id="um_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="lugarentrega_1" id="lugarentrega_1"></select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="direccionentrega_1" id="direccionentrega_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td id="td-not">
        <a title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
        <a title="Detalles" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, just as your error states, `input` is undefined. You are doing things like `input.id` and `input.name` but you never declared `input`. Perhaps you want something like `$(this).attr("id")` and `$(this).attr("name")`.

Comment: I tried using those values. I dont get the error anymore, but still, the atributes are not increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Make use of `this`...**

You're iterating through inputs in the row using `each()`, meaning you can use `this` to refer to the *current* input (instead of `input` which won't work).

```
var newid = $(this).attr("id").replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
var newname = $(this).attr("name").replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
$(this).attr("id", newid).attr("name", newname);
```

---

**2. Your `currentCount` is including the header...**

With 1 data row, `currentCount` is actually 2. Because `2` is not in the `id` or the `name`, no replace is made.

You can either subtract one to compensate for the header:

```
var currentCount = $("#tablaFamilias tr").length-1;
```

...or not include the header in your select by getting a bit more specific:

```
var currentCount = $("tableFamilias tbody tr").length;
```

---

**3. You aren't incrementing your `select` elements...**

You're only incrementing the *`input`* elements, but I have to assume you also want to increment the `select` elements:

```
$('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').find("input, select").each( ... );
```

---

**Put it all together...**

```js
$("#cargarFamilias").click(function() {

  var currentCount = $("#tablaFamilias tr").length-1;
  var newCount = currentCount + 1;
  $('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last');

  $('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').find("input, select").each(function() {
    var newid = $(this).attr("id").replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    var newname = $(this).attr("name").replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    $(this).attr("id", newid).attr("name", newname);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a id="cargarFamilias" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa "></i> Cargar conceptos de familia
</a>

<table id="tablaFamilias" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <th>Partida</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Plazo de entrega</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>UM</th>
    <th>Lugar de entrega</th>
    <th>Dirección de entrega</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="partida_1" id="partida_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="codigo_1" id="codigo_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="descripcion_1" id="descripcion_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="plazoentrega_1" id="plazoentrega_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad_1" id="cantidad_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="um_1" id="um_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="lugarentrega_1" id="lugarentrega_1"></select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="direccionentrega_1" id="direccionentrega_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td id="td-not">
        <a title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
        <a title="Detalles" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your click event should be like following. Two things

1. You need to calculate `currentCount` by `#tablaFamilias tbody tr` selector instead of `#tablaFamilias tr`.
2. Use `attr()` method to set `id` and `name`.

```js
$("#cargarFamilias").click(function() {
    var currentCount = $("#tablaFamilias tbody tr").length, 
        newCount = currentCount + 1;
        
    $('#tablaFamilias tbody > tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#tablaFamilias tbody > tr:last');
  
    $('#tablaFamilias tbody>tr:last').find("input").each(function() {
        var newId = this.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
        var newName = this.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);

        $(this).attr('id', newId);
        $(this).attr('name', newName);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a id="cargarFamilias" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa "></i> Cargar conceptos de familia
</a>

<table id="tablaFamilias" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <th>Partida</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Plazo de entrega</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>UM</th>
    <th>Lugar de entrega</th>
    <th>Dirección de entrega</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="partida_1" id="partida_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="codigo_1" id="codigo_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="descripcion_1" id="descripcion_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="plazoentrega_1" id="plazoentrega_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad_1" id="cantidad_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="um_1" id="um_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="lugarentrega_1" id="lugarentrega_1"></select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="direccionentrega_1" id="direccionentrega_1" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td id="td-not">
        <a title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
        <a title="Detalles" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```